# WCF Callback Deadlocks Even With 'UseSynchronizationContext = false'

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, thread-synchronization, wcf-callbacks

I am stuck with a problem that I can't quite understand.

The problem is related to synchronization between threads on the client side but I can't find the root cause of this.
I created a small demo to simulate the problem, so it will be easier to explain.

**Service Contact:**

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(ITestServiceCallback))]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task RegisterAsync();

    [OperationContract]
    Task UnRegisterAsync();

    [OperationContract]
    int Test1(int i);
}
```

**Callback Contract:**

```
public interface ITestServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void TestCallback(int value);
}
```

**Service Implementation:**

The service upon calling `Test1` method will raise the callback with the value supplied to `Test1` method.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, UseSynchronizationContext = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private readonly HashSet<ITestServiceCallback> _callbacks = new HashSet<ITestServiceCallback>();

    public Task RegisterAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Registering Callback, Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var callbackProxy = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ITestServiceCallback>();
        _callbacks.Add(callbackProxy);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task UnRegisterAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unregistering Callback, Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var callbackProxy = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ITestServiceCallback>();
        bool removed = _callbacks.Remove(callbackProxy);
        Console.WriteLine("Callback was{0} successfully removed", removed ? "" : " not");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public int Test1(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Working on server, Test1, Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        raiseCallback(i);

        Console.WriteLine("Finished on server, Test1, Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        return i;
    }

    private void raiseCallback(int value)
    {
        foreach (var callback in _callbacks)
        {
            try
            {
                callback.TestCallback(value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Callback calling failed in server: {0}", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The Client Code:**

The client is first registering to the server's callbacks (note the async register call - **This is the problem**)
Then calls `Test1`. 
here the call to `Test1` never returns

```
var callBack = new ClientCallback();
var client = DuplexChannelFactory<ITestService>.CreateChannel(callBack, _defaultBinding, _defaultEndpointAddress);
using (client as IDisposable)
            {
                await client.RegisterAsync(); // client.RegisterAsync.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Client Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                try
                {
                    int res = client.Test1(5);
                    Console.WriteLine("Test1 was called, Server Result: {0}", res);


                }
                finally
                {
                    await client.UnRegisterAsync();
                }
            }




[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
    class ClientCallback : ITestServiceCallback
    {
        public void TestCallback(int value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Callback Called, Value: {0}, Thread: {1}", value, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }
```

- When calling `RegisterAsync` synchronously (using `.Wait()`) the call
  to `Test1` does not deadlock.
- The call for `Test1` passes in the server without any problem.
- The binding used is NetNamedPipeBinding:

  Binding _defaultBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding
      {
          MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
          MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
          ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
          SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
          CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue
      };

I thought that when setting `UseSynchronizationContext` property to `false` (in both the `ServiceBehaviourAttribute` and in `CallbackBehaviourAttribute`) should solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have tried ConcurrencyMode.Single on callback class?  does your client code relate to UI thread? 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17704/WCF-Duplex-Operations-and-UI-Threads

Comment: My client test code executes on a console application and do not have any synchronization context (I am setting the ' `UseSynchronizationContext` property to `false` anyway). I will try the ConcurrencyMode option to be Multiple and will update on the result. Thanks.

Comment: I tried setting the `ConcurrencyMode` to `Multiple` on the `CallbackBehaviourAttribute` and it did not work. I get the same deadlock.